# Is computational power of Neural networks related to the activation function

Tags: computability, neural-networks

It is proven that neural networks with rational weights has the computational power of the Universal Turing Machine [Turing computability with Neural Nets](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sontag/FTP_DIR/aml-turing.pdf). From what I get, it seems that using real-valued weights yields even more computational power, though I'm not certain of this one.

However, is there any correlation between the computational power of a neural net and its activation function? For example, if the activation function compares the input against a limit of a Specker sequence (something you can't do with a regular Turing machine, right?), does this make the neural net computationally "stronger"? Could someone point me to a reference in this direction?

Comment: What do you mean by computational power?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I've made some edits to clarify the question. If you have any other edit suggestions, I'd be glad to accomodate them, too

Answer (score 15):

Just a note:

- rational-weighted recurrent $NN$s having boolean activation functions (simple thresholds) are equivalent to finite state automata (Minsky, "Computation: finite and infinite machines",  1967);
- rational-weighted recurrent $NN$s having linear sigmoid activation functions  are equivalent to Turing Machines (Siegelmann and Sontag, "[On the computational power of neural nets](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sontag/FTP_DIR/nets-rational.pdf)", 1995);
- real-weighted recurrent $NN$s having linear sigmoid activation functions are more powerful than Turing Machines (Siegelmann and Sontag, "[Analog computation via neural networks](http://research.cs.queensu.ca/home/akl/cisc879/papers/SELECTED_PAPERS_FROM_VARIOUS_SOURCES/Siegelmann_Sontag.pdf)", 1993);

but ...

- real-weighted recurrent $NN$s with Gaussian noise on the outputs cannot recognize arbitrary regular languages (Maass and Sontag, "[Analog Neural Nets with Gaussian or Other Common NoiseDistributions Cannot Recognize Arbitrary Regular Languages](http://www.igi.tugraz.at/psfiles/95.pdf)" , 1995);

Comment: Is there any paper about the relu activation function?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take the easy solution and say "Yes". Consider an activation function which accepts any inputs and simply returns a constant value (that is, it ignores the inputs). This network always results in a constant output, and thus the computational power (likely by any definition) of this network is zero. It is not capable of calculating anything.

This is enough to show a correlation between the activation function on the the *power* of the network. It of course does not show, nor disprove, that a network could have more *power* than a universal turing machine.